# Add character element in random positions to a list in R

Tags: r

I have a list in R:

```
cls <- list(S1 = c("Start", "K1", "K2", "K1", "Buy"),
        S2 = c("Start", "K1", "K3", "K3", "K2", "Defer"),
        S3 = c("Start", "K1", "K2", "K2", "K3", "Defer"),
        S4 = c("Start", "K1", "K3", "K3", "K1", "Defer"))
```

Now I want to add "K2" to two elements in a random position between "Start" and "Buy"/"Defer".

My approach so far: Choose lines where to add the "K2":

```
set.seed(1234)
idx <- sample(4, 2)
[1] 1 2
```

So I want to insert in lines 1 and 2. To determine the position, I did this:

```
a <- sapply(cls, length)
set.seed(1234)
lapply(a, FUN=function(x) x-sample(1:x-1, 1))
$`1`
[1] 4

$`2`
[1] 2
```

So now I have a list which lines to add the elements in (1 and 2) and what place in those lines (4 and 2).

I found `insert` from package `R.utils` might be useful, but I cannot figure out how to apply it without using a loop. This

```
x <- insert(cls[[1]], ats=c(4), values="K2")
```

works for the first element I want to insert. How can I apply the insert function to all of my list items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're almost there -- it just needs a little bit of rearranging of the pieces you already have.  Rather than sampling all the locations, then sampling the positions in every locations, and then inserting, do the sampling and inserting in one step for each location:

```
randinsert <- function(z) {
   pos <- sample(2:(length(z)-1),size=1)
   return(R.utils::insert(z,ats=pos, values="K2"))
}
```

Now `lapply()` this function to the chosen positions:

```
cls[idx] <- lapply(cls[idx],randinsert)
```